# Catching errors in async functions in an async function

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm not completely sure if the title correctly describes my problem. Please correct me if I'm wrong :)

I would like to call a function to update a user's data in multiple databases/Firebase authentication (the function then calls multiple other async functions). I would like to do all the error handling in the parent function which calls `updateUserData()`. How can I do this?

This is my code:

```
async updateUserData(user: User) {
  // Update Email
  const currentUser = this.getCurrentUser();
  if(user.email && user.email != currentUser?.email)
    currentUser?.updateEmail(user.email)
  
  // Update Display Name
  if(user.displayName && user.displayName != currentUser?.displayName) 
    currentUser?.updateProfile({displayName: user.displayName})

  // Update User DB
  this.firestore
    .collection('users')
    .doc(user.uid)
    .set(user, { merge: true })

  // Update Public User DB
  const publicUserDBRef = this.firestore.collection('public-users').doc(user.uid);
  if(user.displayName && !user.settings.isPrivate) {
    publicUserDBRef
      .set({ uid: user.uid, displayName: user.displayName }, { merge: true })
  } else {
    publicUserDBRef
      .delete()
  }
}
```

I have tried using a `try-catch` block, adding `.catch( error => { throw new Error(error.code) })` to all the async functions in `updateUserData()`, using `return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {...}` (`resolve()` was called at the end of the function, after updating the Public User DB and reject was called in each `.catch()` block)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.set` and `.delete` return promises, but you're not doing anything with those promises. So neither this function, nor any function that calls this one will wait for them to finish. This also means a try/catch cannot catch any asynchronous errors they throw.

If you're ok with waiting for the first `.set` to complete before the `.delete` (or second set) happens, you just need to stick some `await`s on your current code:

```
// Update User DB
await this.firestore
  .collection("users")
  .doc(user.uid)
  .set(user, { merge: true });

// Update Public User DB
const publicUserDBRef = this.firestore.collection("public-users").doc(user.uid);
if (user.displayName && !user.settings.isPrivate) {
  await publicUserDBRef.set(
    { uid: user.uid, displayName: user.displayName },
    { merge: true }
  );
} else {
  await publicUserDBRef.delete();
}
```

If you want both to happen in parallel, then I'd recommend creating an array of promises, then doing Promise.all with them, and either returning or awaiting that promise:

```
const promises = [];
// Update User DB
promises.push(
  this.firestore.collection("users").doc(user.uid).set(user, { merge: true })
);

// Update Public User DB
const publicUserDBRef = this.firestore.collection("public-users").doc(user.uid);
if (user.displayName && !user.settings.isPrivate) {
  promises.push(
    publicUserDBRef.set(
      { uid: user.uid, displayName: user.displayName },
      { merge: true }
    )
  );
} else {
  promises.push(publicUserDBRef.delete());
}

return Promise.all(promises);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty simple, just add try catch around `await`-ed function:

```js
async function parentFunction() {
  // Here was created user
  try {
    await updateUserData(user);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(`e is ${e}`);
    // Some handling of the error
  }
  // ...
}
```